# How do I map multiple <leader> keys in vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to have a left and right hand leader key. If I want both the default `\` and `,` to be my leaders I thought it would be as simple as adding `nnoremap , \` or `nnoremap , <leader>` to my `.vimrc`. But apparently not. How do I do this?

Comment: An alternate solution to having a leader key for both hands: use space. Idea came from Square's dotfiles, https://github.com/square/maximum-awesome

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My `<leader>` is bound to `,` and this works for me:

```
:nmap \ ,
```

All of my leader mappings are now available using either `\` or `,` as the leader. I think it's the `nnoremap` that's tripping you up.

Comment: May you edit your response and make it not depend on your current leader mapping, please? @pyrocrasty suggested :nmamp \ <Leader>

Answer (score 8):

You can map one leader key to the other, as in the accepted answer, but if you're going to use `<leader>` in the first place, you should make the binding to `<leader>` itself. That way the binding will still work if you change (or remove) the first leader key.

```
map , <leader>
```

Note that this still doesn't *quite* work like a second leader. If the first leader is unset, the binding will still work, *but* Vim will also revert to using `\` as a leader, since there is no longer an "official" leader (ie. valid value for the `mapleader` variable). (This wouldn't be a problem for the OP, but may be for others.)

Comment: This is the most precise answer because it does not depend on the current leader key you are using.

Answer (score 3):

`<leader>` is convenient but you can create mappings like `,mm` or `\mm` without using it. Just duplicate all your `<leader>something` and remap them with `'` and `\` directly:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
```

would become

```
nnoremap ,d "_d
nnoremap \d "_d
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly would that work? Vim, when it encounters `<leader>` it replaces it with the mapped key. Were you to use two (keys for `<leader>`), how would it know which one to replace `<leader>` with?

What you can do however, is use `<leader>` and `<localleader>` but that's just two separate leaders, not mapping two keys to one of them.

So, no ... you can't.

*You can map your shortcuts explicitly though.*

Comment: The shortcuts, that's what I'm trying to define. Doing something like ``nnoremap , \`` isn't turning ',' into '\'. If it did, it'd be equivalent to the mapleader effectively giving me two keys that act as the leader. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @TheDeeno - In a way, yeah. Your first mapping 'nnoremap , \' says "whenever I press , replace , with \ and do ... whatever". Then comes the second one that says "whenever I press , replace , with leader and do ... ". One "overwrites" the other.